# How can I convert character like "\u0096" in python?

Tags: python, unicode, decoding

I'm trying to translate this special character `–` from is representation `\u0096` to the character that I want to show. How can I do it? I tried different method using `decode` and `encode` method. Can you please help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? `print` should work.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a json

Comment: U+0096 is an invisible control character. The en dash `–` is U+2013. Whatever produced `"\u0096"` is wrong (probably tried to read a Windows code page 1252 byte string as ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use it in a `json`, you should use [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.loads).

```
json.loads('"\u0096"')
```

Although with that said, I don't think that the encoded representation is the character that you mean it to be. I make `-` to be `\u002d` and your representation to be whitespace.

You can easily do this with larger strings from your files, for example:

```
>>> astring = "\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u002c \u0077\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021"
>>> new = json.loads(astring)
>>> new
'Hello, world!'
```

Comment: This character is inside a complete string of text and i want to put it inside a json

Comment: @TheNobleSix And? I have solved the problem that is in your question. It is very unclear what you are asking me to do now.

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of clarity... I just want to decode every characater like \u(ecc. ecc.) in its equivalent inside a string

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you I realized that the problem is when i try to pass the string to the json.dumps that converts it into the unwanted character

Comment: @TheNobleSiz Glad to have been of assistance. If I have been helpful to you please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).